# Downloading and Uploading file at the same time in C#

Tags: arrays, .net, xamarin

In my mobile app, i've a feature that allow user to download a very large file from Drives and then upload the files to our own drive.

The problem is the file is very large (3gb for example). And we can't store the download file into memory of the phone (which is very limited) and upload it later.

The idea behind is we will download and upload the byte array at the same time. For example, if we have downloaded 5mb, we will upload 5mb to the server immediately and dispose the 5mb out of the memory.

Any idea how i can achieve this? Will i able to implement some kind of Custom "Stream" that will be provided for the HttpClient which can download the same time it provide the binary for the HttpClient?

Comment: You can use `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` in the HttpClient.GetAsync call and handle the stream buffering yourself. Also you could just use a TcpClient to open the "http stream" and set the Request string yourself (http is just a line protocol) and use the socket to receive and re-stream the content via two client sockets